# Turning off auto numbering on the right of equations in eqnarray

Tags: equations, numbering

Here is my part of script.

```
\begin{eqnarray}
\Rightarrow (n+1)^2+5(n+1)+1\nonumber
&=& n^2+2n+1+5n+5+1\nonumber\\
&=& (n^2+5n+1)+2n+6\nonumber\\
&=& 2k+2n+6 \cdots\text{for some $k\in\N$}\nonumber\\
&=& 2(k+n+3)\nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
```

Here, I used \nonumber but I'm being tired to put them everytime I type this thing...

Is there a way to turn off the autonumbering in equnarray?

Comment: @Mico How did you make the "script" part so nice?

Comment: I highlighted the lines in question and clicked on the `{}` "button" in the row above the editing window. Doing so indents the highlighted lines by four spaces, pretty-printing them in the process.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `eqnarray*` instead of `eqnarray` to get an *unnumbered* multiline equation structure.

However, you really shouldn't be using either `eqnarray` or `eqnarray*` -- both environments have been seriously deprecated for many years. Instead, use `align` and `align*`, respectively. For more in-depth references on this subject, see the posting [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5001).

One of the most annoying shortcomings of `eqnarray` or `eqnarray*` is the poor spacing around the alignment point (usually `=`): They insert far more much whitespace on either side of the alignment point than any of the other TeX and LaTeX methods do for typesetting equations. In the code below, compare the excessive amount of whitespace around the `=` symbols in the first structure, generated with `eqnarray*`, with the normal amount in the second structure, which is generated with `align*`.

If nothing else can convince you to give up on `eqnarray`, consider the following: If you switch from `eqnarray` to `align`, you'll save yourself some typing -- the word `align` is shorter than `eqnarray` -- *and* you need to type only one `&` symbol to indicate the alignment point. :-)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\begin{document}

With \verb+eqnarray*+:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Rightarrow (n+1)^2+5(n+1)+1
&=& n^2+2n+1+5n+5+1\\
&=& (n^2+5n+1)+2n+6\\
&=& 2k+2n+6 \qquad \text{for some $k\in\N$}\\
&=& 2(k+n+3)
\end{eqnarray*}

With \verb+align*+:
\begin{align*}
\Rightarrow (n+1)^2+5(n+1)+1
&= n^2+2n+1+5n+5+1\\
&= (n^2+5n+1)+2n+6\\
&= 2k+2n+6 \qquad \text{for some $k\in\N$}\\
&= 2(k+n+3)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```